# Cast between interfaces whose interface signatures are same

Tags: c#, .net, casting

Is it possible to cast from one interface to another when both interface's signatures are same? The below source is giving the `Unable to cast object of type 'ConsoleApplication1.First' to type 'ConsoleApplication1.ISecond'.` exception.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IFirst x = new First();
        ISecond y = (ISecond)x;
        y.DoSomething();
    }
}

public interface IFirst
{
    string DoSomething();
}

public class First : IFirst
{
    public string DoSomething()
    {
        return "done";
    }
}

public interface ISecond
{
    string DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to cast from one interface to another when both interface's signatures are same?

No. They're completely different types as far as the CLR and C# are concerned.

You could create a "bridge" type which wraps an implementation of `IFirst` and implements `ISecond` by delegation, or vice versa.

Comment: I wanted to pass an object which has the same signature as System.Web.Compilation.IResourceProvider to ASP.NET's resource provider model. I had created a custom resource provider which I want to re-use in ASP.NET and in an WindowsService. The custom resource provider, was placed in an Utilities library and I didnt want to take a reference to System.Web in that DLL as it was supposed to be shared between two different types of applications. I also did not want to create a forwarding class i.e. a class that will just pass method calls to the custom resource provider.

Answer (score 5):

As [Jon Skeet already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9428262/14089), no, you can't.

if your problem is to write truely generic code, and if you don't control the interfaces (as in the [solution proposed by Baboon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9428290/14089)), you can still do this two ways in C#:

### 1 - Reflection

...using reflection to query for the method you want to call:

```
object x = new First();

Type t = x.GetType();
MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("DoSomething");
mi.Invoke(x, new object[]{}); // will call x.DoSomething
```

### 2 - dynamic (C# 4)

in C# 4, using the `dynamic` keyword to resolve the call at runtime instead of compile time:

```
object x = new First();

dynamic d = x ;   // every call through d will be resolved at runtime
d.DoSomething() ; // compiles (but will throw if there is no 
                  // "DoSomething" method
```

Answer (score 0):

One way i can think of is this:

```
public interface IDoSomething
{
   string DoSomething();
}

public interface IFirst : IDoSomething {}

public interface ISecond : IDoSomething {}
```

Then instead of casting to IFirst or ISecond, cast to IDoSomething.