# Cast Entity Framework object to another entity framework object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two tables "Product" and "Product_Recovery". They have identical structure.

So, I would like to Cast Product Entity Object to Product_Recovery object and vice versa, but I am getting an error:

> cannot convert from 'MyProject.Objects.Product' to 'MyProject.Objects.Product_Recovery'

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast between interfaces whose interface signatures are same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428247/cast-between-interfaces-whose-interface-signatures-are-same)

Comment: @Aron: Yes, this is a duplicate, but that question is 4 years old and `AutoMapper` may not have been available then. Honestly not sure if the best practice is to leave or close in the case where the referenced question is dated

Comment: @caesay Normally I would say that you should 1) vote to close this question 2) Answer THAT question with your modern answer. However, the top answer there is a Jon Skeet answer, which complicates things....I'm sure there is a meta for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't just cast one object to another unless one derives from the other. How is C# supposed to know that the classes are the same? You can however make the transition from `Product` to `Product_Recovery` by using the `AutoMapper` library, which makes this easier by the use of Reflection.

Check out the [Project Page](http://automapper.org/) or [Getting Started](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started), and install from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) when you're ready to use it.

The simplest example of how to use would be (copied from Getting Started):

```
// execute this somewhere in your program construction 
// only once to generate the required mappings
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Product, Product_Recovery>());

// execute this to transform from one to another:
Product dto = Mapper.Map<Product_Recovery>(productInstance);
```

Comment: Feel free to add .ReverseMap() at the end if you need it both ways.