# Load assembly interface without sharing common library

Tags: c#, interface, assembly-loading

I was wondering if the common library needs to be shared between assemblyA and assemblyB.
What needs to be achieved is loading assemblyA inside assemblyB code and cast the interface as below after loading (from object) one of the types. I read about condition such as some sort of parent class / interface shared between the two interfaces defined in each assembly A and assembly B.  Can we somehow achieve the complete decoupling without having to have to share some type of common library?

```
IInterfaceA
{
   string name {get; set;}
   int  age {get; set;}
   MethodA(int a);
   MethodB(int b);
}
```

The current code bringing in assemblyA during run time would look like:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(mainAssemblyName);
var type = assembly.GetTypes().Single(type => type.Name.Equals("InterfaceA"));
var casted = (InterfaceA)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9428319/2501279) answer your question?

Comment: what do you mean by `decoupling` ? Does it mean that you do not want to have references between assemblies?

Comment: the version control will be dominated by the common lib as necessary. If it would be possible just like rest API, if we can serialize and deserialize as long as compliant to json content.